# asp.net checkboxlist problem, not getting value

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

Then:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
  CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("item1"));
  CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("item2"));
 }
 else
  CheckState();
}
```

Problem is everytime I debug in CheckState(), CheckBoxList1.Item[0].Selected and CheckBoxList1.Item[1].Selected is always false, even if the checkbox is actually checked!

help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the items to your checkbox list in your page initialization code rather than `Page_Load`.

ASP.NET takes the values users post and maps them to your controls during [`PreLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preload.aspx) ([between `Init` and `Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)). If you haven't added the items to your `CheckBoxList` yet, they don't exist yet, so ASP.NET can't select them.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("item1"));
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("item2"));
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        CheckState();
    }
}
```